# Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert

When I put the following code in Viewdidload I returns a warning:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I tried putting it in ViewdidAppear, but then the alert isn't showing up.

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Login"
                                                                              message: @"Input username and password"
                                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Public Key";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Private Key";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
        UITextField * publickey = textfields[0];
        UITextField * privatekey = textfields[1];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:publickey.text forKey:@"privateKey"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:privatekey forKey:@"publicKey"];
        NSLog(@"%@:%@",publickey.text,privatekey.text);
    }]];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you cannot show anything in the `viewDidLoad` is correct, because the view itself is not shown at this point, so there is no way itself can show another view.

However, showing it in `viewDidAppear` should work. But the code you posted here does not include a show command. Can you check if you missed to move this?